# Android Programming: swipe between tabs, remove at ends

Tags: java, android, xml, swipe

I have a swipe between tabs feature in an app I am developing using a FragmentPagerAdapter. My question is: how do I prevent the "can't go any further" animation for swiping at the first and last view?

So, say you have three tabs and you're already on the most far right tab. If you try to swipe right again, that gray/black shadow shows up, indicating that you can't go any further.

Comment: _View.setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)_ programmatically or _android:overScrollMode="never"_ xml attribute has worked for ScrollViews at least.

Comment: Thanks harism. This is just what I was looking for! I just called setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER) on my pager adapter and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FragmentPagerAdapter then it is a default feature of FragmentPagerAdapter what you want.

Comment: Not in my case. It doesn't automatically turn over_scroll_never on.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to show the alert to user.

```
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {              

    int currentPage = pager.getCurrentItem();       //ViewPager Type

    if (currentPage == 3 || currentPage == 0){
        //Write your custom logic here.
    }
}
```

Hope this will help to you.

Comment: Good idea to start with, but harism's solution ended up being much simpler. Thanks though.